# Laravel fill with enum attribute gives error

Tags: laravel, enums, laravel-8, lumen

I have an Enum like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\helpers\Enums;

enum ComissionamentoVendedor: string
{
    case Faturamento = 'No faturamento';
    case Pagamento = 'Após o pagamento pelo cliente';
}
```

And I have a model that uses this Enum

```
...
    public $casts = [
        'comissionamento_momento' => ComissionamentoVendedor::class,
    ];
...
```

But when I try to save it I get an error:

```
$vendedor = new Vendedor;
$vendedor->fill($atributos);
$vendedor->save();
```

The error is `ErrorException: Attempt to read property "value" on string`

It happens on the file `vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:951`

```
 protected function setEnumCastableAttribute($key, $value)
 {
     // $value here is a string, a valid value from ComissionamentoVendedor Enum, sent by the frontend but looks like Laravel expects to be an Enum
     $this->attributes[$key] = isset($value) ? $value->value : null;
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm actually using Lumen 8.3.3.

Comment: what does this array, `$atributos`, contain?

Comment: $atributos contains the values that will fill the attributes of $vendedor. For example: [ "comissionamento_momento" => "Após o pagamento pelo cliente",
  "data_nascimento" => null,
  "tipo" => "Física",
  "genero" => "Feminino",
  "nome" => "João da Silva"]

Comment: because it is expecting an "enum" not a string ... look at the laravel docs for this, they are assigning an enum, not a string

Comment: How can I assign an enum if the value is coming from frontend (React)? I understand that the front would send it as a string and Laravel would do the conversion.

Comment: the version of Laravel you are using is expecting an enum not a string ... check the PHP manual for enums to see how to get your enum from a string value ... otherwise you will have to upgrade to a newer version of Laravel/Lumen 8 to have this resolve the enum from the string for you (that feature was added 2 months ago ... https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/23912e779356715a1719eb3720bd7b9327c5e463)

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of Lumen (8.3.4) but no luck. I think this feature might not have been merged to Lumen yet. Thanks for pointing the direction. If you provide an answer I'll glad accept it.

Comment: how did you upgrade? if i install a fresh install of Lumen it will come with the Illuminate libraries in a current version, 8.80.0,  which has this change

Comment: I upgraded using `composer upgrade laravel/lumen-framework`. But I was able to upgrade to 8.3.4 deleting the lock file and installing again. In version 8.3.4 it have this feature. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you can upgrade the Illuminate libraries being used in your application you don't have the feature of the ability to have the cast get an Enum from a string for you; you will have to pass an Enum. You can get the Enum you need from a string using the `from` method:

```
$enum = ComissionamentoVendedor::from($value);
```

If you are not sure if this value is actually a valid value for the Enum you can use the `tryFrom` method:

```
$enum = CommissionamentoVendedor::tryFrom($value) ?? $defaultEnum;
```

[PHP.net Manual - Language Reference - Enumerations - Backed enumerations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php)

[Github - Laravel Framework - Commit - [8.x] Enum casts accept backed values](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/23912e779356715a1719eb3720bd7b9327c5e463) committed on Nov 15, 2021